# What does "just between you and me" function as?

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

We are trying to figure out the parts of speech in the following sentence and have been stumped by the first phrase:

> Just between you and me, those boots aren't cool this year.

I say interjection, but we think maybe it is some type of adverbial phrase.  What do you think?

Comment: To "figure out the parts of speech" you **first** have to figure out the parts of the sentence, i.e, the constituents (phrases, clauses, subjects, predicates, etc). Then the part of speech should be obvious, constituent by constituent; but doing it word-by-word in a sentence like this is a recipe for misunderstanding.

Comment: @JohnLawler I’ve been fighting that battle in the NLP&CompLing communities. They keep wanting to use simplistic chunkers that have at best ngram awareness, not a real parse, and so they get a great deal wrong. Even the very best of these at per-token assignments still only get 50–60% of the sentences completely correct. Drives me nuts. I blame the Penn Treebank tagset. Well, no not really, but it’s rather subclever.

Comment: CL/NLP does very well in harvesting the low-hanging fruit. It remains to be seen whether parsing is a good CL strategy in the long run. However, there's no doubt whatever that it's the best strategy for a human language analyst. You might find the [last couple chapters of this book](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/book-7.pdf) interesting; they address just that distinction.

Answer (score 4):

*Just between you and me* acts as a **disjunct**, that is, it affects the interpretation of the whole sentence. That may be easier to see if you replace it with an adverb like *confidentially*.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_(linguistics) (after the blackout)

Comment: You can easily circumvent [the blackout](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22911/is-there-a-way-to-get-around-wikipedias-anti-sopa-blackout).

Comment: I agree, and it can also be an adverbial phrase (as in "said between you and me").

Answer (score 3):

"Just between you and me" may be named speech-act related adverb or adverbial. Speech-act adverbial express the conditions under which something is being said. It is "situational adjunct".