# What part of speech is ‘just’ in the sentence “It’s just me”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbs, parts-of-speech, dictionaries, modifiers

I looked up *just* in some dictionaries, and they all say it’s an adverb (or at least, that it **can** be an adverb; apparently it can also be an adjective, a noun, a verb, or even an interjection):

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/just#Adverb)
- [Oxford Learner’s Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/just_1)
- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just)
- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just?q=just_1)
- [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just)
- [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=just)

Then I’m curious as to exactly what part of speech *just* is in this sentence:

> It’s just me.

If it’s an adverb, does *just* modify the pronoun *me* or the linking verb *is*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140574/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-li-what-part-of-speech-is-just-in-the-sentenc).

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: [Is ‘just’ an adjective in ‘just anyone’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/591554); [Just Googling it](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/280624); [What does "just between you and me" function as?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/55176); [Are words like "freaking" and "flippin'" adverbs or adjectives…?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/171488); [The difference between "parts of speech", "word classes", "word categories"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/161989),[What part of speech is "righteous"…?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/116072).

Comment: [How did the adjective “just” come to take on so many adverbial meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217321/how-did-the-adjective-just-come-to-take-on-so-many-adverbial-meanings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ‘just’ an adjective in ‘just anyone’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591554/is-just-an-adjective-in-just-anyone)

Answer (score 6):

## *Just* is modifying *me* here, not *is*

> It’s **just** me.

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> In your example, it's a adverb functioning as a focusing modiﬁer of "me". "Just me" is thus a noun phrase functioning as predicative complement of "be".

Here *just* is an adverb serving as a focusing modiﬁer of the pronoun *me*. It works much like *only* does in this regard, which is another focusing modiﬁer.

But *just* is still considered an adverb here, not an adjective. The same thing happens with *nearly everybody* and *nearly finished*: in both cases, *nearly* is still held to be an adverb even when modifying nouns and pronouns. If this idea seems strange, and I know it may, then this is because “adverb” is a junk-yard category that we throw just about everything into when we run out of names for word classes. It’s also because the simple parts of speech we teach third-graders in America are too narrow and simplistic for use in more nuanced, precise, and exacting analyses.

Boring technical details follow.

---

## Boring Details and References

The *Oxford English Dictionary* allows that *just* can have many possible parts of speech, including not just *noun, adjective, verb, adverb* but also other several others like intensiﬁers and modiﬁers (including focusing modiﬁers) of both words and phrases. This can include nouns and pronouns as well as larger constituents like phrases and clauses.

The particular use mentioned by BillJ as a focusing modiﬁer of arbitrary constituents falls under [OED *just* (adverb), sense 6](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/102192#eid40268469):

> 6. Used to place the focus on a particular word or phrase.
>    a. No less than; absolutely; actually, positively, really. In weakened sense: neither more nor less than, no other than; simply, merely.
>    (a) Modifying noun phrases.

In *just me*, this places the focus on the pronoun *me*.

### And That’s Not All!

However, *just* has many other uses as a would-be adverb. [OED *just* (adverb) sense 2](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/102192#eid40267344) shows *just* used as a modiﬁer of all of these:

- quantiﬁers; adjectives; adverbs; adverbial clauses and phrases; adverbs introducing a subject or object clause; *as* or *so* with adjectives, adverbs, or quantiﬁers; nouns; noun phrases, noun phrases with *the*; prepositional phrases; pronouns; interrogative pronouns; conjunctions; correlative constructions using *not just*; and temporal clauses.

Speciﬁcally, it says it can modify all these types of things:

> 2. As a modiﬁer: exactly, precisely; actually; very closely. Also (now archaic) even just (cf. *even* adv. 5).
>
>    - a. Of place or position, modifying prepositional phrases and adverbs.
>    - b. Of degree and comparison, modifying *as* or *so* with adjectives, adverbs, or quantiﬁers: *equally* or *quite as* ——.
>    - c. Of manner, modifying prepositional phrases, adverbs, and conjunctions, esp. *as, like*. Also of reason or purpose, modifying prepositional phrases and conjunctions.
>    - d. Of amount, number, or quantity, modifying nouns, pronouns, and quantiﬁers.
>    - e. Of time, modifying prepositional phrases, adverbs, and temporal clauses.
>    - f. Of state, identity, or similarity, or of opposition or antithesis.
>
>      (a) Modifying prepositional phrases, nouns, pronouns, and adjectives.  See also just it at Phrases 5, *just my luck* at *luck* n. Phrases 2f.
>
>      (b) Modifying noun phrases with *the*.
>
>      (c) Modifying interrogative pronouns and adverbs introducing a subject or object clause.
>    - g. In **negative contexts** in preceding uses of sense 2.

## Summary

So *just* has numerous complex uses, virtually none of which can be usefully described by a simplistic part-of-speech assignment like “adverb”. It is possible that learners’ dictionaries fail to represent all these. However, if you have a good enough dictionary to consult, not an abridged one, you will discover that these nuanced uses and many are all described there.

Comment: It should be said that "just" and other similar adverbs like "only", "solely" and "merely" etc. modify NPs not nouns or nominals. It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> I think "parts of speech" aren't always helpful. I suppose in principle ***just*** is an "adverb" here, but I don't see how that categorisation would help anyone. I'd say it's far more useful to call it a [***mitigator***](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/intensifiers-and-mitigators) (opposite of ***intensifier***).

Comment: I agree that questions about "part of speech" are rarely useful, normally because the players aren't using a full deck. Even if you pin it down as fine as BillJ, though, what good does it do anyone to know what label to pin on it? Do you make cards to put on sentences? Do you rest secure in your knowledge that you now understand Grammar?

Comment: @JohnLawler I really don't know what the people who keep asking such questions are hoping to answer or learn. I can never figure out what real-world problem they're being presented with that would be solved with a part-of-speech answer.

Comment: Just dropping by to note that "formal" grammar demands a subject pronoun: *It's just I*. But don't ever do that.

Comment: That's why "formal" grammar is a fiction. It's neither formal nor a grammar; it's just a catechism of shibboleths proffered by teachers to those who want acceptance. Most of us outgrow it, just like we outgrow playground bullying. But not everyone; "formal" grammar is just the most socially acceptable form of racism. It has no other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> It's certainly a focusing or limiting modifier, and I'm not the only person who thinks it's sufficiently different from prototypical adverbs to leave it at that.